# understand the following lambda

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method like

```
void Test(Func<bool> f)
{
    f.Invoke();
}
```

I pass in the `Test( ()=>GetItem("123") )`

`f.Invoke()` actually called `GetItem("123")`.

I want to know how does `f` know `GetItem` has a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are passing to `Test` is a `parameter-less delegate` which calls your `GetItem` method.
So your `Test` method does not know anything about parameters to `GetItem`. It only knows about the `delegate` it is calling.

```
Test( ()=>GetItem("123") )
```

is equal to

```
Test(delegate { return GetItem("abc") ; } );
```

which is like calling

```
Test(MyMethod)   
...
bool MyMethod()
{
    return GetItem("123");
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `Test(MyMethod)` and `bool MyMethod() { return GetItem("123"); }` in the last block.

Comment: It think the question got edited after I posted the answer. I edited my answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Your function `Test` takes a function as a parameter.  It will invoke whatever function is passed in as an argument.

In this case, when you create your lambda `() => GetItem("123")`, you are creating a function that takes no arguments, and invokes `GetItem("123")`.

`Test` has no knowledge about the value of the parameter passed to `GetItem`, nor does it need to, because the value of the parameter is hardcoded in the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You're question is a bit confusing. F doesn't know what's required by Getitem.

When you created the lambda, a "pointer" was returned to the place in the memory where a method is located. That method contains the line of code return Getitem("123").
When you invoke F, what actually happens is a kind of jump to a pointer. F is like a "pointer" to that place in the memory where the function is located.

So, to answer your question, F doesn't know what Getitem needs, F just calls the function your wrote, and that function has the "123" parameter hard coded.

Remember that lambda is a type of [Delegate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegate_%28.NET%29)

Answer (score 2):

Good question. You can think of the delegate

```
() => GetItem("123")
```

as being a compiled version of the following expression tree

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        null,
        typeof(X).GetMethod("GetItem"),
        new Expression[] { Expression.Constant("123", typeof(string)) }
    ), 
    new ParameterExpression[0]
);
```

Here I am assuming that `GetItem` is a method defined in a class `X` and that its return type is declared as `bool`.

The point is that the delegate captures all the information it needs to be invoked. When you invoke this delegate in `Test`, you have no idea that the method `GetItem` is behind the scenes, or that it is being invoked with the parameter `"123"`. The delegate is keeping track of that information and `Test` is agnostic to those details. It just wants something that it can invoke that ultimately returns a `bool`. In your particular instance, that `bool` happens to be the result of `GetItem("123")`.

> `f.Invoke()` actually called `GetItem("123")`

Actually it didn't. It called `() => GetItem("123")` which merely returns the value of `GetItem("123")`. See the difference?